# Lagged Fibonacci random number generator with Matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication, fibonacci

So this is the question they asked me:

> Random number generation is the generation of a sequence of numbers or
>   symboles that cannnot be resonably predicted better than by a random
>   chance.  Assume that we use Fibonacci numbers as the sequence and use
>   modula m as the random number. Please write a program to computed the
>   generated number. Input consists several test cases.  Each test cases
>   consists two integers n(0 <= n <= 2,000,000,000) and m(2 <= m <=
>   30,000).  Test will stop with end of file. For each test case, output
>   the generated number (Fib(n) % m).
>
> Input: 1 10 2 10 3 10 4 10 5 10 6 10 7 10
>
> Output: 1 2 3 5 8 3 1

My code looks like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int fibo(int n) {
    if (n==0)
        return 1;
    else if (n==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
}
int main(){
int n;
int m;
while (cin>>n){
if (n>2000000000||n<0)
    break;
else cin>>m;
if (m>30000||m<2)
    break;
else cout<<(fibo(n)% m)<<endl;
}
return 0;}
```

It works but I keep getting this error in the online judge:

> Runtime Error:Segmentation fault

Somehow I got the "right" answer the one the judge accepts. It uses matrix multiplication and somehow this is what they were expecting?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

    int n,m;

    bool input(){
        if(!(cin >> n))
            return false;
        cin >> m;
        return true;
    }

    struct Matrix {
        int data[2][2];
    };

    Matrix Mult(const Matrix &a, const Matrix &b) {
        Matrix c;
        // Martices multiplication
        c.data[0][0]=a.data[0][0]*b.data[0][0]+a.data[0][1]*b.data[1][0];
        c.data[0][1]=a.data[0][0]*b.data[0][1]+a.data[0][1]*b.data[1][1];
        c.data[1][0]=a.data[1][0]*b.data[0][0]+a.data[1][1]*b.data[1][0];
        c.data[1][1]=a.data[1][0]*b.data[0][1]+a.data[1][1]*b.data[1][1];
        c.data[0][0]=c.data[0][0]%m;c.data[0][1]=c.data[0][1]%m;
        c.data[1][0]=c.data[1][0]%m;c.data[1][1]=c.data[1][1]%m;
        return c;
    }

    Matrix Pow(const Matrix base, int exp) {
        if (exp == 0) return base;
        if (exp == 1) return base;
        Matrix sq = Mult(base, base);
        if (exp % 2 == 0)
            return Pow(sq, exp/2);
        else
            return Mult(base, Pow(sq, exp/2));
    }

    int main(){
        while(input()){
            struct Matrix bic;
            bic.data[0][0]=1;bic.data[0][1]=1;
            bic.data[1][0]=1;bic.data[1][1]=0;
            Matrix ans = Pow(bic, n);
            cout<<ans.data[0][0]<<endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: *"It works"* - it does? You plugged `2000000000` into your first code for `n` and it just.. *worked* ? That's *amazing*. That's quite the speedy little rig you have.

Comment: The matrix multiplication is computing the nth fibonacci by calculating the nth power of the `bic` matrix. See here: https://kukuruku.co/post/the-nth-fibonacci-number-in-olog-n/

Comment: @TimothyMurphy this must be it. Recursive Fibonacci is O(2^n) and with the matrix is O(log n). This is for the algorithm analysis lab class.

Answer (score 0):

You used recursive Fibonacci which is most likely overflowing stack for big `n` which causes the `Segmentation fault` error.

No idea what the matrix multiplication has to do with the rest of the question.